# Use view pager from embedded fragment to change spinner in parent activity?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, android-spinner

I'm having a bit of trouble with communication between a parentActivity and its child fragment.

I am using actionbarsherlock.

I have looked around on SO, but I haven't found something that deals with ViewPagers and Spinners yet.

**Background:**

My child fragment has its own action bar specifying a couple of extra action items not available in other fragments, one of these action items is a spinner with multiple options - A, B and C etc

By default the MainActivity will load Fragment_A(child fragment) which contains a ViewPager.

This view pager handles swipes between views A and B(Spinner has options A,B, C etc)

Fragment_A also has spinner adapter. If you select A on the spinner, the viewPager switches to A, if you select B on the spinner, the viewPager switches to B. (This works fine).

**My question is: How do I capture when the user "swipes" between A and B(They don't use the spinner) and change my "spinner" to say A or B respectively?**

Note: My pager adapter(for ViewPager) is created separately in a different class.

Any help is appreciated...Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) is what you need. You'll have to set up an `interface` in your `Fragment` and implement that `interface` in the parent activity. In your `Fragment` instantiate an instance of the `interface` and in whatever method you use to listen to page changes, call the method to communicate that data to the activity.

It seems kinda "hand-wavy" but I hope that clears it up a little.

Comment: I will definitely look into this, but for clarity, would this work between a PagerAdapter and the fragment its used in? My Fragment is what changes the spinner values or sets which spinner is selected. So communication with the main activity is not really happening.

Comment: I went through this as well - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27526

and created an onPageSelectedListener - but its not being called. I do think that getting the onPageSelectedListener to fire would be a more appropriate answer as a solution to my problem. If I can't get it to work, ill work on the concepts you've put forward :)

Comment: The `Fragment` itself should be modular, being able to run on its own as long as it has a parent activity. When you write an `interface` into a `Fragment` that's sort of the bridge where you can send data back to the parent `Activity`, as long as the activity implements that `interface`. If the `PagerAdapter` is part of the `Fragment` then you should be able to send data from it back up through to the parent `Activity`.

Comment: I think if you're going to have swipe gestures though, the listener should remain in the `Fragment` and the `Spinner` in the `Activity` shouldn't need a listener. Just send the callback through the `interface` every time the page changes in the `Fragment`.

Comment: I have three separate classes - MainActivity, Fragment and Adapter. The Fragment uses the adapter and the spinner is a part of the Fragment, not the main activity, that's why I'm getting confused. The reason I've set it up this way, is because my fragments have different items listed in the spinner. So if you're in fragment A - you'll see Options A and B in the spinner, if you're in Fragment B - you'll see options C and D in the spinner.

Comment: In that case you would still use the interface setup to notify the activity. Then in your `Activity`, in the overridden method you get from implementing the interface, make the call to update the other child fragment. Basically, the Activity is how you communicate between fragments.